# How to play videos in Gamemaker Studio 2?

Tags: animation, video, cutscene, game-maker-studio-2

I made a little cutscene in Adobe Animate. I was wondering what would be the best way to have it triggered in game-maker studio 2.

The Video is .mp4 but I could convert it as I have the .fla file saved as well. I wanna figure the how to play a cutscene in game-maker studio 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can play videos through GameMaker Studio 2, but you'll have to open and play the file yourself through extensions or DLLs.

Whilst there were built-in functions to open video files in previous GM versions, these have been marked as [Obsolete Splash Functions](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/017_obsolete%20functions/obsolete%20splash%20functions.html) in GMS1 and don't even appear in GMS2's [Obsolete Functions](https://manual-en.yoyogames.com/#t=Additional_Information%2FObsolete_Functions.htm) list, meaning that they have been likely definitely removed.

---

As stated in the *3rd Party Support* section of GMS2's Obsolete Functions:

> GameMaker Studio 2 moves a lot of built-in functionality from previous versions into extensions...

This is a reasonable decision by YoYo Games to keep the GMS2 codebase clean and move all platform-dependent, OS-specific source code outside and consider it an extension.

Opening a video file is a different operation on different OSs. On Windows or macOS you need a library (DLL or Dylib respectively) to tell the OS you want to open a given video file with a particular codec; HTML5 may not let you do such a thing; mobile platforms have a different way of dealing with flow control.

You can either browse the [GameMaker Marketplace](https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/) and look for the right extension for you, or [create an extension yourself](https://manual-en.yoyogames.com/#t=The_Asset_Editors%2FExtension_Creation%2FCreating_An_Extension.htm) if you feel like coding a little DLL specifically for your project.

Comment: thanks I was able to solve my issue by converting my videos into a .gif then I was able to control playback speeds and stuff which came in handy.